# Mac App mysteriously remembers deleted settings

Tags: mac, applications, settings, preferences, macos

After evaluating several its demo version, I decided to buy [Linkinus](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/linkinus/id402390998) from the Mac App Store.¹ As I had played with the settings a bit, I wanted to do a clean reset before seriously using it.

So I deleted all preference files and folders containing with the app's or its developers's name from my home directory, which were:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Linkinus 2
~/Library/Caches/net.conceited.Linkinus
~/Library/Preferences/net.conceited.Linkinus.plist
~/Library/Preferences/net.conceited.LinkinusSysInfoPlugIn.plist
```

To my surprise, Linkinus still remembered at least a part of its preferences after relaunch.

So I dug deeper, reinstalled the app and also deleted:

```
/private/var/db/BootCaches/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/app.net.conceited.Linkinus.playlist
```

As that didn't help as well, I tried to deactivate iCloud – also without success. I even used [fseventer](http://www.fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software%3afseventer%3astart) to take a look at the files read and written while using Linkinus, but that also didn't give any additional insights.

Can anybody solve that mystery?

---

¹ Yeah I know, the developers appear to have disappeared for a while, but I still like the app.

Comment: Linkinus doesn't appear to create any containers. In fact, I used `find ~ -iname '*linkinus*'` to find the above directories, which also should have caught containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app is pefectly innocent, this is an issue with preference caching on Mavericks.

What finally worked was running `defaults delete $app_id`, so in my case:

```
defaults delete net.conceited.Linkinus
```

**Source:** [Deleting plist file does not reset app on Mac OS 10.9 Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19303958) on StackOverflow